# Best way to add empty space to textfile?

Tags: java, text-files, bluej

I am writing to a RandomAccessFile.  When I try to do `raf.writeBytes("")` the textfile ignores this empty  and just removes it from the file.  Is there a way so that the textfile will save this empty character?

Comment: What do you mean by "empty space in file" and "empty character"?

Comment: `""` is not "empty space" in Java. It is a zero-length string, literally, nothing. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, write an empty char byte data.

```
raf.writeByte(0);
```